# Amazon S3 files are not loading when my computer or mobile device time is set to past time. How can I handle this case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, time

Amazon-S3 files are not loading, when my device time is set to older time. 
what are the settings I need make this work?

Comment: what is the use case? is the time wrong by mistake or are you trying to set the time in the past for other [testing?] purposes?

Comment: It also would be good if you'd update this question to be more specific that "not loading."  Error messages, for example.

Comment: We have tested our webpage in tab and by mistake its time is set to past time (1 year ago). Then we found this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that unfortunately. A timestamp is used in every request and it must be within 15 minutes of the current time:

> A valid time stamp (using either the HTTP Date header or an x-amz-date
>   alternative) is **mandatory** for authenticated requests. Furthermore, the
>   client timestamp included with an authenticated request **must be within**
>   **15 minutes of the Amazon S3 system time** when the request is received

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationTimeStamp

Comment: Good answer. Depending on how the S3 objects are being requested, the client may be able to compensate for clock skew to accommodate this.